# Google Analytics Reporting API v4 vs Google Analytics Data API v1

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get cohort report of user's LTV by country and date.

When using `Google Analytics Reporting API v4` (which is the old api), this is the report request:

```
    request = {
        'reportRequests': [{
            'viewId': '285280317',
            'dimensions': [
                    {'name': 'ga:cohort'},
                    {'name': 'ga:cohortNthWeek'},
                ],
            'metrics': [
                    {'expression': 'ga:cohortActiveUsers'},
            ],
            "cohortGroup": {
                "cohorts": [{
                    "name": "cohort 1",
                    "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
                    "dateRange": {
                        "startDate": "2023-05-01",
                        "endDate": "2023-06-01"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "cohort 2",
                    "type": "FIRST_VISIT_DATE",
                    "dateRange": {
                        "startDate": "2023-06-01",
                        "end_date": "2023-07-01"
                    }
                }],
            }
        }]
    }
```

In the new API for GA4: `Google Analytics Data API v1`, they've changed the API so now you have objects for dimentions & metrics. But how do I use that when getting the LTV?

For a sample report I used it like that (By Google's API documentation):

```
def sample_run_report(self, property_id='PROPERTY_ID'):

    client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()

    request = RunReportRequest(
        property=f"properties/{property_id}",
        dimensions=[Dimension(name="country")],
        metrics=[Metric(name="activeUsers")],
        date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2023-01-10", end_date="today")],
    )
    response = client.run_report(request)

    print("Report result:")
    for row in response.rows:
        print(row.dimension_values[0].value, row.metric_values[0].value)
```

How to I make a request similar to the first one, for obtaining the LTV to the new API?

**[Google Reporting API v4 documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced)**

**[Google Analytics Data API v1 documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the [GA Demos & Tools](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) and log in to your account.
you will see a page like the following photo

[image]

Make sure you are in GA and not UA.
Then, Select your Account and Property.
next, select the dimensions and metrics you need. If your selected dimensions and metrics do not create a conflict, then  you are given a button named: `Query Explorer`.

[image]

clicking on that, it gives you the option to do more filters and you need to set the dates. Finally, if there is no problem and you you don't see any error you can click on `Make Request`

[image]

and then you can see the result something like :

[image]

in my case I could not use cohort so I selected something else.

Comment: Such a great and detailed answer, thanks for your effort!